# Stylus mixins that use the native CSS3 mixins?

Tags: css, stylus

I'm creating a mixin that will allow me to do prefix free styles for `transform: rotate(45deg)`.  The problem is that I have no idea how to do it in proper `Stylus` syntax.  Here's what I have so far:

```
transform-rotate()
    -webkit-transform: rotate(arguments)
    -moz-transform: rotate(arguments)
    -o-transform: rotate(arguments)
    -ms-transform: rotate(arguments)
    transform: rotate(arguments)
```

And then I would like to call it in my `.styl` sheet using the following:

```
transform-rotate(45deg)
```

But when I do that, I get the following error:

```
Cannot call method 'map' of undefined
```

I think the problem is that Stylus is trying to treat the native CSS3 `rotate()` mixin as a custom mixin, and when it tries, it can't find the implementation of `rotate()`.  I'm not entirely sure, but that's my initial thought.

How do I write this out so that it'll compile properly?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need parentheses with Stylus, problem solved !

```
transform-rotate
    -webkit-transform rotate arguments
    -moz-transform rotate arguments
    -o-transform rotate arguments
    -ms-transform rotate arguments
    transform rotate arguments
```

And I'd advise you to use Nib, a stylus plug-in that handles browser prefixing : http://visionmedia.github.io/nib/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That's much more simple than I was trying to make it.  We've now actually moved to SASS, but I'll take your Nib advice if I ever do more Stylus work. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, but frankly i was using LESS before using Stylus and it's so clean to read and code with that i surely won't step back :)